Why is the 'Create Blob (v2)' action not visible in Azure Logic Apps Standard plan but available in the Consumption plan?
I have created two logic apps: one on the Standard plan and another on the Consumption plan.
I can see the create blob(v2) action in consumption plan

But I can't see it in Standard plan. Also, I cannot see it in VScode!


As you can see in the VScode screenshot, Azurite is running in local PC.
Is there a solution?

There are two types of Azure Blob Storage connector present in standard Logic app, one for V1 and the other one is for V2.

When you will search, you will get two results like below-



You will get Create Blob (V2) action in Azure Blob Storage connector present for V2.



Blob created successfully.


Okay, I found it in standard app. But, I cannot see it in VScode! Do I need to change anything in VScode?

@Learner2008 I can see both the connectors in vs code as well. In designer, you are using connectors from Azure or choose skip for now in template while prompted?

I think I clicked on 'Choose Skip'. Now, How can I access Azure connectors in VScode?

@Learner2008 Yes, Indeed if you choose Skip for now option you will see one connector. To use Azure connectors right click on workflow.json file and click here

Thanks for that. Now designer does not load. Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'credentials2'). It seems related to logic app that I recently deleted. I will create a separate SOverflow regarding this.
